# Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^2$ both converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n+y_n|^2$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|^2$ both converge then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n+y_n|^2$ converges. I thought about using comparison test, but $|x_n+y_n|^2\geq |x_n|^2+|y_n|^2$ for any $n$.

Comment: How about comparing $|x_n+y_n|^2$ with $2|x_n|^2+2|y_n|^2$?

Comment: You can use the identity $\lvert x+y\rvert^2=\lvert x\rvert^2+\lvert y\rvert^2+2\Re(x\overline y)\le \lvert x\rvert^2+\lvert y\rvert^2+2\lvert xy\rvert$ and then Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: One way among many: $(x_n+y_n)^2+(x_n-y_n)^2=2x_n^2+2y_n^2$. That settles is for real $x_n$, $y_n$, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\lvert x_n+y_n\rvert^2 \leq (\lvert x_n\rvert+\lvert y_n\rvert)^2
= \lvert x_n\rvert^2+\lvert y_n\rvert^2 + 2\lvert x_n\rvert\lvert y_n\rvert
\leq \lvert x_n\rvert^2+\lvert y_n\rvert^2 + \lvert x_n\rvert^2+\lvert y_n\rvert^2
$$
the last inequality using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) on $\sqrt{\lvert x_n\rvert^2\lvert y_n\rvert^2}$.

Then, the result follows from theorems of comparisons.

---

*Also, side note:* your comment "$|x_n+y_n|^2\geq |x_n|^2+|y_n|^2$ for any $n$" is fishy at best (i.e., wrong). For $x_n=-y_n$, it's clearly false.

Comment: "i.e., wrong" good one